# Do I need to prevent duplicates in Google Places API?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I run a local business community website and I think it would be great to automatically create a google place for each of the businesses that are on my website. The actual business owners are on my website, so their information is accurate.

I can see that in the google places API, I can easily create google places, but what if they already have one? Will it be spammy to auto-create places for them or does google have an algorithm for accepting all results and sorting them on their own?

I think it would have been smart for Google to allow me to essentially create a canonical database for them of what I have and then they can do what they want with it. Is that how it works or do I need to manually ask my clients if they already have a google place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Places API isn't the best way to get data to Google about business location. Currently, the add functions don't allow you to add all the information that you would like to add, including opening hours etc. You can use [Google Places for Business](http://www.google.com/placesforbusiness) instead.

To answer your main question, Google would take results added through either the Places API or Google Places for Business and de-dupe them, but it would help Google and data accuracy to first search for a place, see if that matches and if it doesn't add it.

Comment: Is there an API specifically for Google Places for Businesses? And in order to help not produce duplicates, how can I fool-proof identify what businesses already exist? Is there some kind of unique identifier? Like in google places, is there some kind of unique key like address or phone number?

Comment: No, there is not an API for Google Places for Business. Using GPB there is no unique key. The Places API has a reference which can be used to look up a place, and an id which can be compared. I wouldn't worry too much about deduping though, especially if you're using GPB. Google has good systems in place for that.

Comment: Since there's no API for GPB, I can't automatically create a business place for my members? I want to get them into google places but they're not tech savvy and wont spend the time to do it, and I already have all of their information like hours, etc. So there's no good way to automatically do this? Each business has to be added by hand?

Comment: Unless I'm reading it incorrectly, GPB bulk is for a single business with lots of locations. I run a community of businesses, not just one. I have 1,000 *different* businesses that need to be added.

Comment: Then you should ask in the help forum for GPB if there's any other solution for you.